# Export multiple values from a single Combo Box? (Adobe Acrobat)

Tags: javascript, api, sdk, acrobat

I'm trying to export 2 values from every single item from the combo box field.

I have found two methods to insert items into a combo box:

1) insertItemAt

http://www.verypdf.com/document/acrobat-forms-javascript/pg_0048.htm

2) setItems

http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9/Acrobat9_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=JS_API_AcroJS.88.748.html

but neither method allows two parameters (im always get "missing ) after argument list" error from the Acrobat JavaScript Debugger)

Does anyone know of a better solution for this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

try giving an array to setItems....

Comment: Could you bit a little ore elabroate?